# How do I fix - XmlRootElement cannot be resolved to a type - error

Tags: java, jax-rs

I'm learning Java + Jax-Rs
I’m working with Eclipse 2022-06
When I try to use @XMLRootElement I get the error – “XmlRootElement cannot be resolved to a type”
In my pom.xml file I have:

```
    <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You have a mismatch in versions. Hibernate 6.1 is Jakarta EE 9, which means it uses `jakarta.*` as the package namespace for the Jakarta EE libraries like JAXB, etc. While that - unreleased(!) - JAXB API you're importing is from Java EE 8 (using the `javax.*` package namespace). Make sure you either use only libraries from/depending on Jakarta EE 9 (which includes JAXB 3 or higher), or only libraries from Jakarta EE 8 or lower (which would mean switching to Hibernate 5.6 or lower, and JAXB 2.3). Also make sure you use released versions and not intermediate builds like this one.

Comment: Sorry but I did not quite understand you. From what I see Hibernate 6.1.2 was officially release on August 3'rd 2022. My interpretation to what you wrote is that the relevant Jakarta version was not released for this Maven version. So, now I need to downgrade my Hibernate to version 5.6.11. How do I do that? Just change the dependency?

Comment: Jakarta 9 has been released for a while now, but given the massive change triggered by renaming the package names from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`, you can't just combine random versions of libraries and hope it will work. You need to understand the versioning of the libraries you're using (and especially with Jakarta dependencies, also know that the Maven coordinates changed). Probably downgrading the Hibernate coordinates to 5.6.11.Final will do the trick, but there might be more libraries you need to change versions (e.g. JAX-RS).